# Absolute value equation - 2020 values - alternative solutions

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I stumbled upon an interesting problem and I wonder whether you see any interesting alternative solutions.
I am particularly interested in the method that allows to determine the number of possible cases.

The problem is the following:

Find all values of $l$ that satisfy the equation below:

$|x-1|+|x-2|+|x-3|+⋯+|x-2019|+|x-2020|≤l$

So currently I am using the following absolute value property:

$|a|+|b|+⋯+|n|≥|±a±b±⋯±n|$

With this I consider the two cases, where the x simplifies (I show only one case for simplicity - they have the same resulting value):

$|x-1|+⋯+|x-2020|≥|(x-1)+⋯+(x-1010)-(x-1011)-…-(x-2020)|$

$|x-1|+⋯+|x-2020|≥|-1-2-3-…-1010+1011+⋯+2019+2020|$

$|x-1|+⋯+|x-2020|≥1020100$

$l∈[1020100,∞[$

And now I am wondering. Do you see any other method to solve the equation, apart of the property I showed above?

I know there are these methods with considering different cases. But how many cases are there? Is it 2021?

I am waiting for your opinions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is piecewise linear, with a slope regularly increasing from $-2020$ to $2020$, in steps $2$. Thus it has a flat single minimum which is reached on the symmetry axis, in $[1010,1011]$. The function value is indeed

$$1009+1008+\cdots 1+0+1+2+\cdots1010=1020100.$$

To illustrate, the function with $6$ instead of $2020$.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have two questions to you. 

We have different "function" values. Does that mean that I have calculated mine wrong? Are you sure of your solution?

Additionally, how many cases do you see for the piecewise function? Am I right about 2021?

Comment: @Hi_I_like_math_a_lot: sorry, there was a typo in my result. We agree.